# How to change list column that is defined as multi-line to single line input

Tags: 2010, list, column

I have imported an excel document into SharePoint 2010. One of the columns was automatically defined as being multi-line, but I want it to be single line input instead. I have looked at redefining the column as single line but I am not presented with the option to do so. How can I overcome this problem and redefine the column (without losing all the data associated with it)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change it. I think You have two (more or less bad) options.

- Delete the column (and then lose the information in it) and create it again with the correct properties.

or

- Rename the column and create a new (with the name of the old and set it to Single Line). Copy the Content from the "renamed" column into the new.